# SFMC Ampscript failing validation using a lookup for a synced Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Salesforce MC error:

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when
> attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for
> detail. Script Expression:
> Lookup("PUBLIC_SCHOOL_DISTRICT__C_SALESFORCE","Number_of_Community_Interests__c","Id",%%PublicSchoolDistrictId%%)

```
<div>
    %%[/* Pull the Current CIL count */
    Var @cilCount
    Set @cilCount = Lookup("PUBLIC_SCHOOL_DISTRICT__C_SALESFORCE","Number_of_Community_Interests__c","Id",%%PublicSchoolDistrictId%%)
  ]%%
    Count: %%= v(@cilCount) =%%
    </div>
```

I'm not sure about my placement within the HTML email.  I inserted this code inside the  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    %%[
/* Pull the Current CIL count */
    Var @cilCount
    Set @cilCount = Lookup("PUBLIC_SCHOOL_DISTRICT__C_SALESFORCE","Number_of_Community_Interests__c","Id",PublicSchoolDistrictId)
  ]%%
    <div> 
Count: %%=v(@cilCount)=%%
    </div>
```

The `PublicSchoolDistrictId` doesn’t need the percentage signs as it’s used inside an AMPscript block. I also removed the spaces around the `v` function and moved your `div` further down. AMPscript doesn’t need to be wrapped in HTML (but it can if needed).

Comment: That was it the %% inside my %%[]%%.  I tried multiple options in-line without success.  Any thoughts on the Best way to do that?  Does the lookup work just inside like this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/lookup.html

Comment: Thank you for your assistance